# Does import sql dump wipe out current data?

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql dump from version 5.5.50. I want to import it into a mysql instance on another machine, running version 5.7.13. I am using the following command to do the import:

```
mysql -u root -p dbname < /home/dump.sql
```

I want to be sure that this command will completely overwrite everything on the new mysql instance. That instance already has a database with the same name and some temp data in it.

Or should I manually drop the database on the new instance prior to doing the import to ensure they're completely identical after the import?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

it is totally dependent on your `mysqldump` process and which options you have used while dumping. There are options like `--add-drop-database`,`--add-drop-table`  etc with `mysqldump` which results to wipe out your existing database with same name.
see [mysql docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html) for futher details.

Comment: Why you suggesting the options "--add-drop-databas". It's Caution regarding --add-drop-database for live database https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/backing-up-and-migrating-a-site/restoring-a-database-backup-command-line

Comment: He needed `--skip-add-drop-table` (etc)